# Docker build unnamed first stage in multi stage pipeline

Tags: docker, build, dockerfile

**Introduction**

I'm currently writing a generic script to automatically cache stages for a multi stage dockerfile

The way I envision it to work is to automatically go through a dockerfile, find all the different stages (basically search for `FROM .... AS ...` Once the code finds this, I can then do a docker build where I tag this specific stage as something like imagename-stage:firststage.

However as the documentation describes you can also have multi-stage docker files without a name:
https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#use-multi-stage-builds

Example:

```
FROM golang:1.7.3
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/alexellis/href-counter/
RUN go get -d -v golang.org/x/net/html  
COPY app.go .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o app .

FROM alpine:latest  
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
WORKDIR /root/
COPY --from=0 /go/src/github.com/alexellis/href-counter/app .
CMD ["./app"]
```

In the example above you refer to the previous stage by adding `--from=0`

**Problem**

When i try to target the first stage in a dockerfile that contains no `AS ...` I would expect I could do something like:

```
docker build . --target 0
```

However when i do this, I get the following error:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  49.99MB
Error response from daemon: failed to reach build target 0 in Dockerfile
```

Does someone know how to resolve this?

**Edit:**

I also posted this question on the docker forum, but so far I haven't seen a response: https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-build-first-stage-in-multi-stage-pipeline/91167

Comment: Perhaps it's not possible, as the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#specifying-target-build-stage---target) say: _When building a Dockerfile with multiple build stages, `--target` can be used to specify an intermediate build stage **by name** as a final stage for the resulting image._

Comment: I hope this is something that could be added in the future :)

Comment: I didn't search through issues, so I'm not sure if someone has proposed it. But I think there's a way to submit your ideas and then people are upvoting and they are prioritizing some issues based on how much people need it.